# How to call a function from another file, but use a variable from the current one?

Tags: python, function, variables

So how to call a function from another file but use a variable from the current one?
I think it's very simple, but I can't get the desired effect. I keep getting an error that there is no such variable, even if I write 'global settings'
Here is a sample code.

```
from modules.module import *

settings = "Hello world"
displayText()
input()
```

FIle 2

```
def displayText():
    print(settings)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should pass the variable as a *parameter* to the function.

Answer (score 0):

add a parameter in your `displayText` function.

```py
def displayText(settings):
    print(settings)
```

Pass the parameter from the actual file

```
from modules.module import *

settings = "Hello world"
displayText(settings)
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, you can pass a variable to a function. That has to be defined as a *parameter* in the function definition. Look at the below example:

```
def print_value(value):
    print(value)
```

Value here is a *parameter variable* that can be passed to the function by calling it with your variable:

```
name = "My Name!"
print_value(name)
# Prints out: My Name!
```